# Validate and Update structure (tables, columns) of an old mysql database, based on a newer version of this database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I build a CRM application in .NET for commercial use.

For the database, I choose the MySQL server.

Every new software version need changes to the MySQL database structure (add columns, add tables, alter the type of a column, etc).

I need to find an efficient way when I publish a newer software version

- To validate my clients' database based on my original (latest) MySQL database
- To update my clients' database if changes exist.

Comment: Why MySql? It was great back around 2005, but it really hasn't kept pace with other options. For windows, Sql Server Express is free to distribute with your app. If you want open source, Postgresql is light-years ahead of MySql these days.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you very much for your suggestion. The only reason that made me to choose MySQL, was that SQL Express has a size limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by the statement in you question:

> Every new software version need changes to the MySQL database structure (add columns, add tables, alter the type of a column, etc).

If you are developing a commercial CRM application then it is a bad practice to require a database update in EVERY new version. That implies bad design and analysis. The point to my comment here is that you should design your application in a way that it doesn't need a database update in every new version.
Next, in the same statement you wrote: "alter the type of a column". Believe me, you DON'T want to do that in a customer's database with data present. You should never be in a position that you need to alter the type of a column in a database with data in it. There is no space here to analyze that but take my word for it.

With that being said let's proceed to your question.
If you are building a commercial application with a database then you actually have 3 options regarding the db update requirement.

1. Do everything by hand. Maintain your own db upgrade scripts from version to version and apply them as required. That's the most painful way to do it but it gives you the freedom to do everything you want. Including altering the type of a column. If your application is relatively small then you should prefer this method.
2. Use a free ORM library like [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/). That will give you more flexibility on focusing in the business logic of the application as it eliminates the need for most of the data-access code that developers usually need to write. Moreover has various ways to automatically migrate the database. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/) for example. If your application doesn't have any special or uncommon requirements regarding its data persistence and access then you should go with this.
3. Use a commercial ORM library like [DevExpress XPO](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/orm/) (actually is free if you don't want to buy support but I strongly recommend to buy it). You will get all of the benefits of an ORM library plus many enhancements like for example data filtering customization, in client data processing, easier handling of BLOB data like images or other binaries, broader database support like SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Firebird etc. I am using XPO for years now and I am quite happy with it. If your application has special data manipulation needs then I recommend this.

**Conclusion:** You should definitely go with an ORM library because it allows you to separate the business logic of your application from the data layer and doesn't bind the application with one type of database and thus gives you more flexibility. For example you can create a BOM (Business Object Model) of your application and use it with many variants like a web API, desktop clients, web apps etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extended analysis. In this project I build modules and most of the times is needed to create a new table and more rare to fix the structure. The "EVERY time" may be an exaggeration.I ask, because I dont want to miss something by keeping the changes manually. Thank you again for the solutions you provide.